# 500.shtml in drupal logs

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, logging

what reasons may be cause the 500.shtml page not found error in drupal logs. how to fix it. thank you.

Comment: This has little to do with Drupal, but is caused by the server-configuration. I suggest you start looking there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 500 represents the server encountering an internal error.

You are seeing 'Page Not Found (500.shtml)' in the logs because the server is encountering an internal error and looking to display that file (500.shtml) to tell the user more about the error, etc. You need to either create the file 500.shtml and add to the correct path, or change the path where the server will look for the file by editing the web server (apache?) configuration.

A similar question has been posted at Drupal Answers: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/lots-of-500-shtml-page-not-found-errors-in-logs/1229#1229